# Can Amazon web service can be used for webdriver functional testing?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2

Is there any possibility to run functional webdriver tests in actual browser not headless mode in aws instance? xvbf and Firefox has been installed.

I have tried to run but getting below error:

```
process:5133): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:275)
```

Comment: I guess http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-run-gui-applications-xfce-on-an-amazon-aws-cloud-server-instance/ would be roughly what you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify *DISPLAY* environment variable, for example:

> export DISPLAY=:99

And then run xvfb using this number, like:

> xvfb :99

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give a try on Display variable first if that was the missing puzzle.

The number has to be :99 time or it can be any random number?

Comment: As I remember any number from 0 to 99 and you need to specify it when you run xvfb, like "xvfb :99". Updated my answer.